# How can I achieve port forwarding with IPTables?

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, iptables

I need to achieve the following scenario using IPTables:

[image: Scenario Image Link]

In this scenario we have a front end server with only one NIC with IP `1.2.3.4`, and there are three other servers with IPs set to `172.20.20.20`, `192.168.20.10` and `10.10.10.8`.

The goal is to configure IP tables so that clients only connect to the front end server (`1.2.3.4`) and the request get forwarded based on the port, for example when the green client requests `1.2.3.4:8080`, the request is sent to `10.10.10.8:8080`, or if he sends a request to `1.2.3.4:443`, his request is forwarded to `172.20.20.20:443` while preserving the original client's IP.

I need this IP as a part of user identification - based on the client's IPm different contents will be served.

I have already read these questions but it didn't help:

- [IP forwarding with iptables](https://superuser.com/questions/503224/ip-forwarding-with-iptables)
- [Port forwarding with IPTABLES and VBox](https://superuser.com/questions/431864/port-forwarding-with-iptables-and-vbox)

Comment: set he linux box as default gateway on all three servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the firewall/router - issue the following commands (assuming you want this to work on Port 80.  The first provides the path to the webserver, the second corrects the outbound leg.

```
IPTABLES -t nat A PREROUTING -p tcp  -d REAL.WORLD.IP --dport 80  -j DNAT --to-destination INTERNAL.IP
IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s INTERAL.IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source EXTERNAL.IP
```

Comment: Dear @davidgo, Thanks for your answer but I think it doesn't satisfy the "while preserving the original client's IP." part of the question. Does it?

Comment: Yes, it does.  The first command rewrites the destination (not the from address), the second rewrites the from address - but only after its left the server, so the logging will show the correct source address.  (I took these commands from  a live system, so I'm quite sure of myself)

Comment: I just realised that I did not specify the -t  nat option in the rules above. This is required as well.